# Insert and Update Two Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Key':('A','B','C'),
    'Value':(25,30,45),
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Key':('A','B','C','D'),
    'Value':(35,25,45,60),
})
```

I would like to combine `df1` and `df2` such that for a particular key (let's say "A"), if the value in `df2` is larger than its value in `df1`, I take the value from `df1`, but if the value in `df2` is smaller than its value in `df1`, I take the value from `df2` (for example key "B").  If the key is unique (for example key "D"), I need the key and value in the new dataframe.

The expected output is as follows:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 25 |
| B | 25 |
| C | 45 |
| D | 60 |

Can anyone help me to do this in python using pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Use `concat` and group and find the minimum:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Key', as_index=False).min()
  Key  Value
0   A     25
1   B     25
2   C     45
3   D     60
>>>
```